# Button text with no/smaller padding

Tags: android

I have a button and would like top and bottom of text was touching top and bottom border of button.

But I'm not able to remove that padding or whatever it is and there's a considerable space between top of text and top of button border. It looks like this:

[image]

This is code:

```
<Button a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="match_parent" a:background="#ffff0000" 
a:minWidth="1px" 
a:minHeight="1px" 
a:maxHeight="1000dp"
a:paddingHorizontal="15dp" 
a:paddingVertical="0dp"/>
```

Any idea or hint how to remove that spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a:layout_height to wrap content, which wraps the button height to content of the button.

```
a:layout_height="wrap_content"
```